# DNN Frame work changed

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have an old DNN website. which is been updated through the years and is now on Version 6.2.8. I want to update it to version 7 which requires .net framework 4.0. When I change my framework version on plesk from 2.0 to  4.0 I get "500 Internal Server Error". This is a dedicated Server. All the other similar websites i upgrade before didn't gave my such a problem

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what might be causing the problem without seeing a specific error message. If you go to the site from a browser on the server, you might be able to get a more detailed message on the error. You could also try setting CustomErrors in your web.config set to off but that often doesn't work for 500 errors. If neither of those work, you could look in the EventLog table in the database and see if an error is being written out.

Comment: Nothing of the above helped :(

Comment: I've always been able to see more detail using one of those methods. The only other idea I have then is to look at the Event Viewer on the server (not the DNN Event Viewer but Windows) and see if you can see any more detail there.

Comment: It seems that something is not right in the structure of the web.config but i can not understand what...